# Is it possible to create opensuse package from ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, build, opensuse

I have an Ubuntu system with all the dependencies installed in it. I am able to build the application for Ubuntu, but now I wanted to build the same for openSUSE.

Comment: found these two helpful links.
https://fusion809.github.io/package-development/#toc17
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/02/rpm-build-package-example/

Comment: This is not directly possible, since your local library versions and stuff like that differ from those installed on other systems. I suggest you take a look at SUSE's open build service which allows everyone to prepare packages for a multitude of systems in a proven and capable environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a deb package first and then using Alien(sudo apt-get install alien) converted it to rpm package. OpenSUSE supports rpm package installation.

Hope this will help someone.